# Scraping an image from a webpage

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to download an image from a webpage using Scrapy, the thing is that the page is a bit complicated, so I think I'm not defining correctly the xpath.
The spider runs with no errors, however, no image is saved into the folder I specified. I'm new to scrapy so I'm stuck at this point. The webpage is inside the code... Any suggestions will be well received. Thanks!

```
import scrapy
import re
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose, TakeFirst
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from imagetest.items import ImagetestItem
from imagetest.items import ImageItem

custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
        "IMAGES_STORE": '/Users/jose/Desktop'
    }

class imagetestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "imagetest"
   allowed_domains = ["dataviz.worldbank.org", "worldbank.org"]
   start_urls = ["http://dataviz.worldbank.org/t/DECDG/views/IFC4/DSHB_MCT02h?:embed=y&:display_count=no%22;%20break"]

   def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath("//html/body"):
        item = ImagetestItem()
            img_url = sel.xpath('//*[@idd="view2429655783888868492_8474849571036086192"]/div[1]/div[2]/img').extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, img_url),callback=self.parseImages,  meta={'item': item})

   def parseImages(self, response):
    for elem in response.xpath("//img"):
            img_url = elem.xpath("@src").extract_first()
            yield ImageItem(image_urls=[img_url])
```

Comment: Does anybody have an idea about how scrape the data from that webpage rather than downloading the image(s)? The table values don't appear in the html code...

Comment: which one is the actual url that you want to scrape?

Comment: I am trying this one: http://dataviz.worldbank.org/t/DECDG/views/IFC4/DSHB_MCT02h?:embed=y&:display_count=no%22;%20break

Comment: that url contains no images

Comment: the table is actually a .png image, you can see it here: http://dataviz.worldbank.org/vizql/tilecache/5708D9B44F0E48D696101E5C52FA9B7A-0:0/9100/198cfb35cb014aee1c926ba17dbc417eab29f4ec50686f5ca83e781c4b5cfd82/views.2429655783888868492_8474849571036086192.viz.0.0.png?=1525869624409Z3

Comment: i don't believe you can do it with scrapy, as the website is rendered on the client side. im sure there is a better way to it, but i would download those images and use an OCR

Comment: I'll try... thanks!